# How do I start kestrel from a test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I'm setting up regression testing for my ASP.NET 5 project using beta8. When I setup the test fixtures I want to fire up kestrel so that I could run selenium tests against it without the need for any external web server. How do I do this?

It's basically something like this:

```
public class RegressionTests : IDisposable
{

    public RegressionTests()
    {
        // Start kestrel
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.True(true);
        // more tests...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Shutdown kestrel
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried so far but I couldn't get it to work. It doesn't pick up the project.json file. Well, to be honest, I don't know what to pass to it since I can't find anywhere what command args I can pass to `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program`.

```
new Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program(CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider).Main(
            new[] 
            {
                "--server",
                "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
                "--project",
                "../Web/project.json",
                "--port",
                "5001",
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Victor Hurdugaci. For the google folks of the future, this is what I ended up having. This is a test fixture that I use for xunit. The `TestConfiguration` class is missing but you should get the idea. You need to add a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Testing`.

```
public class WebTestsFixture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IApplicationDeployer _deployer;
    private readonly IDisposable _loggerScope;

    public WebTestsFixture()
    {
        var logger = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddConsole(LogLevel.Information)
            .CreateLogger("Regression");

        _loggerScope = logger.BeginScope("RegressionTestSuite");

        var deploymentParameters = new DeploymentParameters(
            TestConfiguration.Configuration.Get<string>("Settings:ApplicationPath"),
            (ServerType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ServerType), TestConfiguration.Configuration.Get<string>("Settings:ServerType")),
            RuntimeFlavor.Clr,
            RuntimeArchitecture.x86)
        {
            ApplicationBaseUriHint = TestConfiguration.Configuration.Get<string>("Settings:ApplicationUri"),
            EnvironmentName = TestConfiguration.Configuration.Get<string>("Settings:EnvironmentName"),
            PublishWithNoSource = false
        };

        _deployer = ApplicationDeployerFactory.Create(deploymentParameters, logger);

        DeploymentResult = _deployer.Deploy();
    }

    public DeploymentResult DeploymentResult { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _loggerScope.Dispose();
        _deployer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

@mardoxx [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740003/how-to-host-the-kestrel-server-in-a-test?noredirect=1#comment86495059_49740003) that a more modern and much simpler approach to testing is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing#integration-testing-aspnet-core).

Comment: While your point is valid, he specifically asked for running Kestrel. The TestServer package doesn't launch an actual webserver, which means there are certain edge cases you can't test (like whether CORS works)