# Use web project config.json when doing integration testing

Tags: testing, integration-testing, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET 5 RC1 and I need to write integration tests ...

So on the Test project, ASPNET5_WEB_TEST, I have the following:

```
public class IntegrationTests {

  private readonly TestServer _server;
  private readonly HttpClient _client;

  public IntegrationTests() {

    _server = new TestServer(TestServer.CreateBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
    _client = _server.CreateClient();

  }

  // Test methods ...
}
```

The Startup class is from the ASP.NET 5 project I am testing: ASPNET5_WEB

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
The configuration file 'C:\Projects\ASPNET5_TEST\config.json' was not found and is not optional.
```

I know I get this error because on Startup I have:

```
  builder
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", false)
    .AddJsonFile($"config.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
```

To fix this error I need to copy, at least, config.json from my web project, ASPNET5_WEB, to my test project, ASPNET5_WEB_TEST. But this means I will need to maintain duplicate config.json or at least copy it every time I make a change.

Can't I tell TestServer to use Startup of the web project and also its config.*.json files?

And can I have a config.testing.json and set on the TestServer the environment to Testing so the Startup code uses config.json and config.testing.json?

Comment: Can you please give more details about the error? Who's throwing it? What do you have in the `Startup` class? It's just a guess but probably you have code in `Startup` that expects a `config.json` file

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Yes, it is true that Startup expects config.json ... But can't I make the TestServer to use the config.json of the Web project and add an extra config.testing.json to it? I just updated my question ... Does it help to clarify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the `TestServer` from `aspnet`, if so, it wasn't built to support the way you're config files are read. The `TestServer` is used to run *simple* integration tests for their "hosting engine" but not for integrations tests for a website.

Their [ApplicationDeployerFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Testing/Deployers/ApplicationDeployerFactory.cs) class is what you can use however. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33771514/1461061) as an example of how to run an "integration" server. I've used selenium in conjunction with that to run integration tests against the project I'm working on atm.

Comment: On my web project i also have an api. I am not using a self hosting api. So i need to test it to ... but even if it was a self hosted api does not also have config.json? What do you mean the way config files are read? Is there another way?

Comment: I was following this post: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/12/17/asp-net-5-web-api-integration-testing/

Comment: @Miguel What do you mean by self hosting api? Another way to get your `TestServer` working is to pass an `IConfiguration` instance to the `TestServer`'s constructor. You'll have to build it yourself when setting up your test though and you'll probably need something in your `Startup` that tells it not to read the config.json files if you're testing.

Comment: If you're testing "simple" stuff then that article should be sufficient. You'll find that if you have a more complicated project that it's better to use the `ApplicationDeployerFactory` though. If you could add one of your test methods, that'll probably be helpful as well.

Comment: I mean a project with only an api ...  but of course in asp.net is the same ... yes I can disable the read of config while testing and have the testing values in the startup code. But does this make sense? Can I define a environment variable for testing when i start the test server?

Comment: If you want to keep using `TestServer`, I'm afraid that's the only choice you've got unless you can find a way to change the base path of where you're tests are ran. Yes, you can define a variable. That's one way. It's a bit hacky though but I guess you don't have a lot of option.

Comment: In terms of testing i need to test ef context and also controllers (mvc but also the api ones which are in fact the ones i need more testing). I do not need test server. I am loooking for the better option. In which kind of tests should i use testserver?

Comment: Use `TestServer` to test simple responses. If you are trying to do a full integration testing I recommend you check the SO link in my answer. That runs a standalone kestrel server (the url you can control of course), write selenium tests to test html or just use `HttpClient` if you want to test json responses from your API. The `ApplicationDeployerFactory` will run your website the way you're expecting it to. No hacks. All it does is fire up another dnx instance which is exactly how it starts up if you run `dnx-watch`, `dnx web` or IISExpress.

Comment: Deployer is for multiple servers configurations. Check my answer, it can be done easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Take a look at this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3410 and The mentioned package.

Basically you need to implement your own `IApplicationEnvironment`